# How to use RxJava in a normal retrofit call?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

**Context**: My current application uses normal `retrofit calls` in order to get data from the `api`. I really wanted to introduce `RX` into the calls but I don't have much experience with that. I read some things online and none of them show me a simple way to do this. I'll show you what I have.

**Purpose**: To turn what I have into `RXJava`

**This is my code :**

My generic perform call method that I want to convert into `RXJava`:

```
fun <T> performCall(call: Call<T>?, callback: OnRequestCallback<T>) {
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
                when (response.code()) {
                    200, 201 -> {
                        callback.onSuccess(response.body())
                    }
                    else -> {
                        callback.onError(response.errorBody())
                    }
                }
                return
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
                callback.onError(null)
                Log.d("Network Manager Failure", t.localizedMessage)
            }
        })
    }
```

Then to have a context from my activity I use this method that calls the perform call method:

```
fun <T> BaseActivity.callAPI(call: Observable<T>?, onSucceed: (T?) -> Unit, onError: (errorCode: String) -> Unit) {
    NetworkManager.instance.performCall(call,
        object : NetworkManager.OnRequestCallback<T> {
            override fun onSuccess(body: T?) {
                onSucceed(body)
            }

            override fun onError(errorResponseBody: ResponseBody?) {
                JSONObject(errorResponseBody?.string()).let {
                    val errorCode = it.getJSONObject("meta").getString("errorCode")
                    when (errorCode) {
                        Errors.DEPRECATED_API_VERSION.name ->
                            onAppUpdateNeeded()

                        else -> onError(errorResponseBody)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Then the `BaseActivitt.callApi()` is used in every activity that needs api information, I now the use of `view models` + `dagger` is better but for now is what I have and I have to keep it.

Can someone show me how to turn this into an `RXJava/Kotlin` thing?

Comment: You don't need to do the conversion manually. Retrofit can return an `Observable`. Just take a look at this simple [explanation](https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae)

Comment: Yes but on my perform call I really wanted to use the Rx methods instead of the standard provided by retrofit to prepare the app for the future

Comment: you need to change the definition of `callAPI`. It should not take callbacks. It should return the observable and then the caller will subscribe. In this way, you will be able to combine observable. Same thing for `performCall`. With RxJava you should try always to return observable and then subscribe at the end of the pipe.

Comment: Can you show an example @kingston?

Comment: Mmm it is really difficult to do here something better than what you can find googling  "rxjava api call". Anyway your snippet would not compile: the call parameter is defined in different ways.

Comment: To be honest I think that with rxjava both these methods would become redundant as rxjava already has a really good way to propagate error and success events. So in a way, the answer I'd give you is to scrap these 2 methods and change your API calls to use Rx.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't like the idea of having these generic handlers. I had to work on a project that was written like that and it wasn't a nice experience: what happens if, for example, you want to handle the `Errors.DEPRECATED_API_VERSION` in a different way for a call?

Anyway, I would do something like this: from Retrofit return the Observable and then in the place where you need to make the call subscribe to the Observable.

```
val disposable = service
        .yourApi()
        .map { value ->
            MyCommand.SuccessCommand(value)
        }
        .onErrorResumeNext { ex: Throwable -> YourObservableThatEmitsTheErrorCommandOrTheOnAppUpdateNeededCommand() }
        .subscribe { command: MyCommand ->
            when (command) {
                is MyCommand.SuccessCommand -> {
                }
                is MyCommand.ErrorCommand -> {

                }
                is MyCommand.AppUpdateNeededCommand -> {

                }
            }
        }
```

The command can be implemented something like

```
sealed class MyCommand {
    class SuccessCommand<T> (value: T): MyCommand()
    class ErrorCommand (val ex: Exception): MyCommand()
    object AppUpdateNeededCommand: MyCommand()
}
```

Comment: Please consider that I wrote this here so take it with a grain of salt and this is just one of the thousands of way to implement it

Comment: And of course you can put everything that is before the subscribe in a data-layer/repository class